# Using google sheets api without client side login

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a website that fetch data from a Google spreadsheet. I would like my users to see the fetched data without logging in. Is that possible and how?

In order to fetch and update sheet data, I just need one account, ideally signed in at the server side. However I haven't seen any server side logging without the need of a client side login.

Answer (score 7):

Based from this [link](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing), when your application requests public data, the request doesn't need to be authorized, but does need to be accompanied by an identifier, such as an API key.

> Every request your application sends to the Google Sheets API needs to identify your application to Google. There are two ways to identify your application: using an [OAuth 2.0 token](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing#AboutAuthorization) (which also authorizes the request) and/or using the application's [API key](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing#APIKey). Here's how to determine which of those options to use:
>
> - If the request requires authorization (such as a request for an individual's private data), then the application must provide an OAuth 2.0 token with the request. The application may also provide the API key, but it doesn't have to.
> - If the request doesn't require authorization (such as a request for public data), then the application must provide either the API key or an OAuth 2.0 token, or both—whatever option is most convenient for you.

Here are additional reference which might help:

- [Google Sheets API: client side 'service account' authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47121504/google-sheets-api-client-side-service-account-authorization)
- [Access Google spreadsheet API without auth token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44045183/access-google-spreadsheet-api-without-auth-token)
- [Write to a Google spreadsheet from JavaScript using the Public API access (no OAuth)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29332794/write-to-a-google-spreadsheet-from-javascript-using-the-public-api-access-no-oa)

Answer (score 2):

My late answer for your question: we need at least CLIENT_KEY and API key. See my quick start code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google Sheets API Quickstart</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Google Sheets API Quickstart</p>

    <pre id="content" style="white-space: pre-wrap;"></pre>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Client ID and API key from the Developer Console
      var CLIENT_ID = 'CLIENT_KEY';
      var API_KEY = 'API_KEY';

      // Array of API discovery doc URLs for APIs used by the quickstart
      var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4"];

      // Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
      // included, separated by spaces.
      var SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly";

      /**
       *  On load, called to load the auth2 library and API client library.
       */
      function handleClientLoad() {
        gapi.load('client', initClient);
      }

      /**
       *  Initializes the API client library and sets up sign-in state
       *  listeners.
       */
      function initClient() {
        gapi.client.init({
          apiKey: API_KEY,
          clientId: CLIENT_ID,
          discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
          scope: SCOPES
        }).then(function () {
          listMajors();
        }, function(error) {
          appendPre(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
        });
      }

      /**
       * Append a pre element to the body containing the given message
       * as its text node. Used to display the results of the API call.
       *
       * @param {string} message Text to be placed in pre element.
       */
      function appendPre(message) {
        var pre = document.getElementById('content');
        var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n');
        pre.appendChild(textContent);
      }

      /**
       * Print the names and majors of students in a sample spreadsheet:
       * https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
       */
      function listMajors() {
        gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
          spreadsheetId: '1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms',
          range: 'Class Data!A2:E',
        }).then(function(response) {
          var range = response.result;
          if (range.values.length > 0) {
            appendPre('Name, Major:');
            for (i = 0; i < range.values.length; i++) {
              var row = range.values[i];
              // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
              appendPre(row[0] + ', ' + row[4]);
            }
          } else {
            appendPre('No data found.');
          }
        }, function(response) {
          appendPre('Error: ' + response.result.error.message);
        });
      }

    </script>

    <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
      onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
      onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: does this include for writing to the sheet, ie can you send data to the sheet from an application even if a user isn't logged in to google (assuming you have client id and api key accessible in your application)?